# Loop through values of a SPSS variable inside of a Macro

Tags: macros, spss

How can I pass the values of a specific variable to a list-processing loop inside a macro?

Let's say, as an simplified example, I've got a variable *foo* which contains the values 1,4,12,33 and 51.

```
DATA LIST FREE / foo (F2) .
BEGIN DATA
1 
4 
12 
33 
51 
END DATA.
```

And a macro that does some stuff with those values.

For testing reasons this Macro will just echo those values.
I'd like to find a way to run a routine that works like the following:

```
DEFINE !testmacro (list !CMDEND)
   !DO !i !IN (!list)
     ECHO !QUOTE(!i).
   !DOEND.
!ENDDEFINE.

!testmacro list = 1 4 12 33 51. * <- = values from foo.
```

Comment: Given your problem description macros (by themselves) are not the way to go. The macro facility doesn't have anyway to grab the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made myself a little bit familiar with Python recently :-)
So this is what I worked out.

**If the variable is a numeric:**

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spss,spssdata
foolist = [element[0] for element in spssdata.Spssdata('foo').fetchall()]
foostring = " ".join(str(int(i)) for i in foolist)
spss.Submit("!testmacro list = %(foostring)s." %locals())
END PROGRAM.
```

**If the variable is a string:**

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spss,spssdata
foolist = [element[0].strip() for element in spssdata.Spssdata('bar').fetchall()]
foostring = " ".join(foolist)
spss.Submit("!testmacro list = %(foostring)s." %locals())
END PROGRAM.
```

### Variants

**Duplicates removed and list is orderd**

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spss,spssdata
foolist = sorted(set([element[0] for element in spssdata.Spssdata('foo').fetchall()]))
foostring = " ".join(str(int(i)) for i in foolist)
spss.Submit("!testmacro list = %(foostring)s." %locals())
END PROGRAM.
```

**Duplicates removed and items in order of first appearance in the dataset**

Here, I use a function which I retrieved from [Peter Bengtsson's Homepage (peterbe.com)](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark)

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spss,spssdata

def uniquify(seq, idfun=None): 
   # order preserving
   if idfun is None:
       def idfun(x): return x
   seen = {}
   result = []
   for item in seq:
       marker = idfun(item)
       if marker in seen: continue
       seen[marker] = 1
       result.append(item)
   return result

foolist = uniquify([element[0] for element in spssdata.Spssdata('foo').fetchall()])
foostring = " ".join(str(int(i)) for i in foolist)
spss.Submit("!testmacro list = %(foostring)s." %locals())
END PROGRAM.
```

### Non-Python Solution

Not that I recommend it, but there is even a way to do this without Python. 
I got the basic Idea from a SPSS programming book, which goes as follows:
Use the WRITE command to create a text file with the wanted command and variable values and include it with the insert command.

```
DATASET COPY foolistdata.
DATASET ACTIVATE foolistdata.

AGGREGATE OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
   /BREAK
   /NumberOfCases=N.

* Variable which contains the command as string in the first case.
STRING macrocommand (A18).
IF ($casenum=1) macroCommand = "!testmacro list = ".
EXECUTE.

* variable which contains a period (.) in the last case, 
* for the ending of the command string. 
STRING commandEnd (A1).
IF ($casenum=NumberOfCases) commandEnd = ".".

* Write the 'table' with the command and variable values into a textfile.
WRITE OUTFILE="macrocommand.txt" /macrocommand bar commandEnd.
EXECUTE.

* Macrocall.
INSERT FILE ="macrocommand.txt".
```

Comment: Every time I see Python and SPSS-macro syntax next to each other, I have to admire how awful SPSS syntax really is

Answer (score 2):

This is a situation where using the Python apis would be a good choice.